# Saving a Managed Object with a To One type

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am new to iOS development and I am trying to get my head around using multiple managed objects.

For example the test app has a two entities one for Folder, and another for Planner. It is a To One type so for every folder there is a planner. Planner has an attribute called notes to save the text from the text field.

After creating a folder, tapping on the cell in the tableView the user segues to the planner view controller passing on the `selectedFolder` object. Within the **Planner View Controller** I am trying to make sure when the `savePlanner` function is executed this should save the the 'UITextView' text to the 'notes' property of the managed planner object which has a direct relation with the 'selectedFolder'.

I am unsure how I make sure there is a relation between the Planner and Selected Folder when saving.

In the Planner View Controller I have;

```
class PlannerViewController: UIViewController {

//SelectedFolder is the managed object of the cell row
var selectedFolder: Folder!
var planner: Planner?

@IBOutlet weak var plannerTextField: UITextView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

//Load Planner Data in text field here..


}


@IBAction func savePlanner(sender: AnyObject) {

    //Save Planner Notes To Folder

    //Get the context
    let moc = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
    //get entity details
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Planner", inManagedObjectContext: moc!)
    //Create the managed object to be inserted
    let note = Planner(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: moc!)

    //Add current Planner to selectedFolder
    selectedFolder.planner = note

    //Error
    var error: NSError?
    if moc!.save(nil){}

    //Storing Data
    note.notes = plannerTextField.text

    moc?.save(&error)

}

}
```

Comment: Maybe your terminoligy is confused, but you should only have a single managed object *context*- You have multiple managed objects.  Assuming `selectedFolder` is an instance of your Folder managed object, simply assign the note `selectedFolder.planner=note`

Comment: Sorry, I realised when I re-read the post, made some edits. Hmm I'm not sure how that would help me save the textfield.text to 'notes' in the 'folder' class.

Comment: I don't see anything about a textfield in your question, however presumably you would store the text in an attribute of the `Note` entity. The line in my comment shows how to set the relationship between a folder and note, although thinking about it you probably want a to-many relationship between the folder and the note with a to-one inverse relationship. If you set this up in your model then simply assigning the `selectedFolder` to the inverse relationship attribute in your `Note` entity will do what you need

Comment: i have re-read your question and your comments, and I realised it isn't clear what you are asking- is it how to establish the relationship between folder and planner?  Is it how to update an existing planner object that is already associated with the folder?  Is it how to put the text into the planner?

Comment: @Paulw11 Alright, my apologies. When I mentioned modify the text I meant `plannerTextField`. So the `savePlanner` function should save the text to the note property in the Planner class. The Planner entity should be associated with the `selectedFolder`. I hope that makes sense. So in the end Every folder will have a planner with notes in a text field that can be displayed and modified.

Comment: It is a bit confusing because your code is always allocating a new Planner - you should only do this if there isn't an existing Planner object. If there is an existing Planner then you don't need to do anything to the folder, you just update the existing object. To store the text, simply assign it to `note.notes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a one-to-one relationship you can set it from either side. Do this before saving. Thus:

```
selectedFolder.planner = note
// or
note.folder = selectedFolder
```

Of course, this will only work if you have set up the relationship and reverse relationship correctly in the Core Data model editor.

Comment: I have already set up the relationship in the data model. I updated my code, unfortunately receiving an error when executing the save function. [Testapp.Planner count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: The new error has nothing to do with the original post. You should accept this answer and ask a new question.